# How to unlink an app from google drive account

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

I'm linking my app via google play services - drive api. Works fine until I tried to unlink my application form user's google drive account. I found a way using Plus API like;

```
mApi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
    .addApi(Drive.API)
    .addApi(Plus.API)
    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .build();
...
...
Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mApi);
mApi.disconnect();
```

But this actually didn't help me much. When I re-link to my app to google drive, account selection intent didn't shown up. (My account doesn't have Google Plus service activated !)

Is there any other way to unlink an app from google-drive. I wonder why Drive::DriveApi::clearDefaultAccount doesn't exist ?

**Edit :**

Well, as a workaround ;

```
mApi.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
mApi.disconnect();
```

This will clear authentication data and mApi.disconnect() don't let the Reconnect ... I still wonder if there any elegant solution ...

Answer (score 3):

As you see, the method `clearDefaultAccount()` is deprecated and replaced with `clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect()`.

The method `clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect()` removes the default account set in Google Play services for your app. Subsequent calls to `connect()` will return a resolution intent that will let the user select a different account.

If the user chooses the same account, no consent will be required since access to the app is not revoked. Users should also be given the option to revoke access with `revokeAccessAndDisconnect(GoogleApiClient)`.

You may find more information on the link: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/Account.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: i just try quickstart sample i have some error please see this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636659/upload-file-to-google-drive-using-google-play-serivces-libwithout-supporting-ja please help me